# Sobre instalación de Visual Studio Professional 2022, no me aparece en la lista de plataformas la versión 8 a pesar que ya está instalada

Tags: vb.net, net, framework, vs

No aparece la versión 8 en la lista, entonces seleccioné "Instalar otras plataformas" e instalé la versión 8, pero sigue sin aparecer ¿Alguna sugerencia para intentar que aparezca?

La lista a la que me refiero es esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez en la documentación de .NET te pueda sacar de dudas. Aquí te dejo un [enlace](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations) a la pagina oficial y al problema especifico que puedas tener.

Comment: Gracias por el enlace, lo voy a a revisar. 

Comment: Parece ser un error el hecho de que no las muestre, salvo mejor explicación. No creo que sea cuestión de incompatibilidad porque son versiones más recientes. Se supone que lo más reciente es más compatible. Pero lo que puedo compartir es que probé cargar un proyecto hecho con la versión 2019 y al abrirlo sí aparecen seleccionada correctamente la versión respectiva y corre bien.

Comment: .net 8 ???? te refieres a una preview??  si es así te vas a ayuda->buscar actualizaciones -> cambiar la configuración de actualización -> canal de actualización : Preview